# PHP file upload in Webview

Tags: php, android, kotlin

I just built an android app using Kotlin, everything on the app works perfectly except for when I try and upload files through the app.

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mWebView : WebView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        try {
            this.supportActionBar!!.hide()
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView) as WebView
        mWebView!!.loadUrl("https://www.chinookwindslogistics.com")
        mWebView!!.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        mWebView!!.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

    }
    override fun onBackPressed(){
        if(mWebView!!.canGoBack()){
            mWebView!!.goBack()
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.Xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crayonsandcoloringbooks">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

Can Anyone help me with figuring out how to allow file upload to work within this app? Thank you so much in advance, sorry I am still new to Kotlin.

Comment: How PHP is related to Android app written in Kotlin?

Comment: what error you are getting? can you post your error logs